# How to prevent some specific apps receiving signal from rotating-sensor

Tags: android, rotation, android-sensors

I notice that the way android rotate my device is very annoying ( esp, when you viewing images...)
For my app, I can set it in portrait or landscape mode in manifest file( and a setting feature to set when user want it).

But what I want was have a general setting that can set other apps ( other already installed image viewers) to stop receiving signal from sensors ( so that other images viewers will work just like my app), while other apps still work normally with rotating sensors.

I don't know where to start to implement this feature ( I have thought about intercepting broadcast signal from sensor, but that thing seems to be dangerous).
Where should I start ? any clue or recommendation is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Stop auto rotation for your device

Comment: I still want this rotating function for other apps, just want to stop it from some app ( as I say like image viewer app). And it seems someone did not try to read all the question before giving a minus :(

Comment: And how will your app detect other apps that are Image Viewers? Short of disabling the System's orientation, I am not sure if an alternative exists.

Comment: It doesn't matter, if I know a way to stop this, I can list all apps available on devices to set it stop auto-rotate. So if user don't want app auto-rotate, just set it. That's what I means

Comment: Can't you change global system settings (like disabling auto rotation) programmaticly? Or did you need to be rooted for that?

Comment: I have thought about disable global setting, but there are some others app that we don't need to stop auto-rotating. Is there any idea like intercepting broadcast message to a specific app? Like that, we can control which app will not be able to receiving signal from rotating sensors.

Comment: But if you create a service that checks whenever a certain started app is listed by your own app, you can disable and enable screen orientation whenever it is needed right? Start an app -> Check if app is listed -> it's not listed -> don't change global settings.

Comment: thanks Edward, good idea to try :) I definitely know that someone with  their brilliant ideas on stackoverflow could help me out :)